# Is there a tulip-flower lens hood that will work with the Nikon AF Zoom-Nikkor 35-70mm f/2.8 D?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, lens-hood

I'm looking for a Tulip Flower Lens Hood for Nikon AF Zoom-Nikkor 35-70mm f/2.8 D?
I know that Nikon HB-1 and HB-15 hood work on this lens. But do you know any Nikon or third party Tulip Flower Hood?

Comment: @Rene those hoods have a straight front edge (so they are *not* tulip hoods)

Comment: Tulip hoods weren't "in" when that lens was, so I'm sure you won't find one specifically for it. Perhaps something compatible exists...

Answer (score 4):

The front of the AF Zoom-Nikkor 35-70mm f/2.8D (both the hood bayonet and filter thread) rotates during focus. Therefore a petal type lens hood would not be correctly aligned most of the time. Hence the recommended hood(s) for this lens are of the simple round type.

http://www.photosynthesis.co.nz/nikon/accessory.html#xx-70

Answer (score 3):

You could try [printing your own lens hood](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/) on a piece of cardboard. I haven't tried it out myself, so I can't comment on the quality.

If you have a full-frame camera you should use [this link](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/hoods/Nikon-AF-Zoom-Nikkor-35-70mm-f-2.8-D.php).
If you use a frame with a 1.5 or 1.6 crop factor then you need [this lens hood template](http://www.lenshoods.net/hoods/Digital-Lenshood-Nikon-AF-Zoom-Nikkor-35-70mm-f-2.8-D.php).

I'm not affiliated with this site, just remembered it when I saw your question.

Comment: I think this is really the best answer. That's because while there are 62mm filter thread lens hoods which probably could be used, they seem to mostly be for wider-angle lenses than 35mm, making it kind of pointless (especially if you're putting it on APS-C). So, make your own that fits exactly your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a couple of lens hoods from ebay and they all worked fine considering the price - even some plastic tulip shaped. You could just buy a couple of them for $2 each and try it. Sometimes, there is a bit of tape needed to hold the tulip in place so it doesn't rotate but hey, even Joe McNally does it.
When You have your hood, please make sure you test for light fallof - if the hood is too deep.